# How would you design a 3-D roller coaster track using mathematical modelling?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, education, parametric

I have an assignment where you design a roller coaster using mathematical functions in two dimensions. However, obviously this is not very realistic as it only consists of two dimensions, so only vertical and horizontal parts of the track can be modeled which neglects the parts of the roller coaster that go "in and out of the page" so to speak. I would be interested in learning how one would go about doing this in three dimensions.

Comment: Not much changes from two to three dimensions. But the one new thing you play with is torsion - the twisting of the track without bending in a circle.

Comment: There are two important considerations: banking the curves and shaping the curvature so that there is no abrupt change in the acceleration (i.e,. *jerk*) on the curves. The latter part calls for the Cornu spiral to assure a uniform change in the lateral acceleration. The former part calls for a vector analysis of the of the velocity and forces acting on the car.